# Using Delphi autocomplete

Tags: delphi, autocomplete

I have an enumeration type:

```
TParameterType = (CPT_NONE, CPT_INT, CPT_DOUBLE, CPT_STRING, CPT_STREAM);
```

I selected it and after an unknown action somehow it was automatically pasted like this:

```
 case Parameter.ParamType of
      CPT_NONE: ;
      CPT_INT: ;
      CPT_DOUBLE: ;
      CPT_STRING: ;
      CPT_STREAM: ;
    end;
```

How to repeat it?